# How to tear down a brick chimney

Tags: brick, masonry, chimney, demolition, flue

My 100 year old chimney is in bad shape, so I decided to tear it down and rebuild it. Prior to beginning, I thought it was just the bricks and a steel liner, however once I took off the crown and the first course of bricks, I could see that there was also the original clay liner.  I have a couple of questions:

1. What is a good way to tear down the clay liner?  The first section seems to be about 2 feet high, 1 foot wide and about an inch thick. I'm working alone, so I don't think I can just lift it off safely.
2. When I rebuild the chimney, can I just build the brick part and run a stainless steel liner through it without any sort of clay liner?  In other words, is the clay liner providing some sort of structural purpose for the chimney that I am unaware of?

My chimney is not used for a wood burning fireplace, rather, it is an exhaust for a gas boiler and a gas water heater.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If a big chunk falls down the chimney and get stuck half a way that is going to be fun.

Comment: Clay looks fine so just rebuild the bricks around it.

Comment: @Solar Mike I'm concerned if I take down all the bricks and just leave the clay, it may be unstable during the time it takes me to rebuild the brick.  The chimney is about 7 and 1/2 feet.

Comment: Use some guy lines to support it then, or add scaffolding poles to do so - many options....